# Icebreakers to use with strangers

Tags: usage, set-phrases, conversations, daily-life

Let's say I am in a gym and had an eye contact with a person working out next to me, is it OK to say

> 今日は、如何ですか。
>
> どうも、元気か。

What are the best simple expression to break the ice with complete strangers?

Comment: Have you considered こんにちは? (Or こんばんは or おはようございます, don't know what time of day you're working out.)

Comment: Yes, but I want to say something more than just a greeting.

Comment: すみません、何時ですか。is a good one!

Comment: はじめまして、よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these sound a pretty unnatural and even in English I can't think of many times where I would just say "how are you" to break the ice to someone working at the gym next to me. Something just like `こんにちは` is good because they will most likely reply back, and you can use that as a bouncing point. After that you can say something like `スニーカー、かっこいいね` (Your shoes are pretty cool) or some other "in." If they don't reply back and just nod, it's most likely a no-go (depending on the situation) but other things you could say to start something are:

`ああ、疲れた~` - Saying this out loud after eye contact or `こんにちは` might prompt a response like `お疲れ様です` and maybe can lead into a conversation

`すみません、今何時ですか` might work if you can lead into some kind of conversation after asking the time.

Just a word to the wise, but you should probably figure out if the eye contact is a "I'm interested in chit-chat" and not a "Oh a non-japanese person is in the gym"